# tlmgr: TeX Live 2011 is frozen forever

Tags: installing, texlive

I recently installed TeX Live 2011 (basic) and ran `tlmgr` command. The output said `No command 'tlmgr' found, did you mean....`. As a remedy I exported the directory where `tlmgr` is located to $PATH variable by running `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux/:$PATH`.
After doing this if I run `tlmgr --self --all update`, I get following message:

```
tlmgr: package repository http://get-software.net/systems/texlive/tlnet
TeX Live 2011 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2011/tlpkg/backups
tlmgr: no updates available
```

I installed TexLive 2011 using `sudo` command and `sudo` version of above command does not help either. Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: TL 2011 is now frozen.  You need to wait for the 2012 release.  See [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/).

Comment: Did you actually read the message? It's pretty clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The TeX Live team freezes a version (e.g. 2011) shortly before the next one (e.g. 2012) is coming out. This means no new packages updates will be incorporated from CTAN or other sources. You can still update an older installation to the last versions before the freeze, but further runs of `tlmgr update` will not do anything. It prints the above *info* text to tell you this, which is technically not an error.

Note that you can't upgrade from one TeX Live version to the next, but rather need to install the new version as a fresh install.
You just happened to install TeX Live at a bad time, so you will have to install it a few weeks again if you want to get package updates.

Comment: Not actually true. One cannot upgrade on Windows, the TL team released a few scripts such that Linux users could upgrade TL10 to TL11. Worked just fine.

Comment: @daleif: I was always wondering about this. Thanks!

Comment: Then again I do not know what is so special about Windows, that makes it impossible to upgrade it in a similar fashion.

Comment: @daleif: Either the file system (hard links are possible under NTFS but very difficult) or the tool set (a lot more tools under Unix/Linux by default).

Comment: @MartinScharrer And: We should be thankful that the TL-team each year use a lot of time and effort to compile an application like TL for _free_ use, even if updating from one version to  another is a little more complicated than pushing a button.

Comment: @Sveinung: I wasn't complaining. ;-)

Comment: @daleif: the special things about windows are mainly the registry entries for file associations and the uninstaller. On Unix, TL is just a bunch of files, on Windows it's a little bit more.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I don't think we use hard links. Concerning the tool set, we have Perl, which should be enough :)