# Defrosting: How to manually install TeX packages

Tags: texlive, mactex

I have a `BasicTex` installation (downloaded [here](https://tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html) and based on the MacTeX2013 distribution) running on OSX. I need to add some additional packages that are not included in the installation (actually no package is included). But apparently

```
TeX Live 2013 is frozen forever
```

that is, I can't

```
tlmgr install mypackage
```

until TeX Live 2014 is online.

How could I still install the packages I need from CTAN? Which file do I need? Where do I put them?

Comment: Nice title!  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57698/15925

Comment: @AndrewSwann I read that message. But could I just download the package files manually and reference them? Just until the new release

Comment: OK, I think I found how to do it: [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installing_Extra_Packages#Manual_installation)

Comment: You can still use `tlmgr` to install packages, they will just be the versions frozen a few weeks ago.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Are you saying that `tlmgr install mypackage` keeps installing the package? Because I don't get any shell message from running the command apart the `frozen forever...` one. But I actually haven't checked if the package was installed anyhow...

Comment: Yes, the install command should still work.  If you are running in a shell it should tell what it has done.  Also running `tlmgr info babel` will tell you for example whether `babel` is installed or not.

Answer (score 1):

My online book [*Formatting Information*](http://latex.silmaril.ie/) has full details of how to create a [Personal TeX Directory](http://latex.silmaril.ie/formattinginformation/personal.html) (used for private or additional material not covered by tlmgr) and install packages in it (http://latex.silmaril.ie/formattinginformation/pkginst.html#installpkg).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `--force` option, i.e. `tlmgr install --force ...`

Comment: Don't do this! It is unnecessary and dangerous. In no case could it possibly help with the problem reported.